# "The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':compileKotlin'." When Gradle building

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, compilation, wrapper

Enviroment:
gradle-6.5.1
Kotlin
JSF

Hello everyone.
I had to move from Intellij because my licence expired And I was trying to buil my project using Gradle(As I was already doing before) using VS Code.

When I try to run my project with the usual  `gradle build -info --build-cache` so when I try to compile my kotlin code it gets stack in the same part every single time:

```
> Task :compileKotlin
Deleting stale output file: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\cloud\build\classes\kotlin\main
Build cache key for task ':compileKotlin' is 3bd7d5460a493fb5a0944ec8a3be0e80
Task ':compileKotlin' is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':compileKotlin'.
Using Kotlin/JVM incremental compilation
<-------------> 0% EXECUTING [4m 16s]
> :compileKotlin
```

It dosen't throw an error, it just stays like so for hours and hours.

I also updated from gradle-5.2.1(It didn't ork in that version neither) but when running the scan my gradle.build doesn't seem to have any problems, just some deprecated but still useful instructions: [My scan results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6lQM.png)

Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening?